# Gmail feed with a Google Apps email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, feeds

I'm trying to get a Gmail feed to work with my Google Apps email. The feed works by using the following URL:

```
https://#GmailUsername#:#GmailPassword#@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
```

The problem is, in order to sign into Gmail with my Google Apps email, the username has to be the full email address, and that doesn't work with the above URL because of the double `@`.

```
https://name@mydomain.com:password@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
```

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
https://#username#%40#Domain#:#Password#@mail.google.com/a/#Domain#/feed/atom
```

Replace #username# #domain# and #password# with your data and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, although for URL decoding @ translates to "%40" i.e.

```
"username%40domain.com"
```

This does work when used in a browser (logged out of all google accounts and tested with

```
http://username%40domain.com@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
```

format) ..it displayed the xml with no issue, although with my rss reader (rainmaker, various plugins) It does not seem to receive the feed.

Hope this helps slightly